# Dynamic variables in base R

Tags: r

How to create please dependent variables in R ? 
For example

```
a <- 1
b <- a*2
a <- 2
b
# [1] 2
```

But I expect the result 4. How can R maintained relations automatically ?
Thank you very much
**Explanation - I'm trying to create something as excel spreeadsheet with the relationships (formula or functions) between cells. Input for R is for examle csv (same values, some function or formula) and output only values**

Comment: I don't understand, what's the difficult of updating b every time you change a, or even better, don't use b, use 1*2 directly

Comment: I think the OP is asking to do something that is inadvisable but I think it's clear what they want to do.  I disagree with the close vote for the reason of "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: With that said it probably would be beneficial if the OP described *why* they want to do this as I'm sure there is a better way to do what they want to do.

Comment: I am a complete beginner.
I really try something like spreadsheet
Thank you all. Use the function will be a good solution

Comment: Note I'm voting down some of the "not good ideas" because although this *is* possible, its very ill-advised in R, and it probably should only be used by experts who know what they are doing. Hope answerers don't mind too much, but I think R beginners need pointing in the right direction.

Comment: @Spacedman I don't care about downvotes but I highly disagree with your methods here.  I provide a warning that it's not a good idea.  There are other answers that provide better alternatives but my answer DOES solve the problem as asked in the question.  I would kindly ask you revert your downvotes and instead put comments placing your concern.  Also it appears you downvoted the other answers (maybe it wasn't you?) but that just seems wrong to me.

Comment: @Spacedman I don't understand the need to downvote, why not just leave a comment? Also, I don't understand exactly how my solution is "very ill-advised", it's simply illustrating the use of lexical scoping

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you're looking for `makeActiveBinding`

```
a <- 1
makeActiveBinding('b', function() a * 2, .GlobalEnv)
b
# [1] 2
a <- 2
b
# [1] 4
```

The syntax is simpler if you want to use Hadley's nifty `pryr` package:

```
library(pryr)
b %<a-% (a * 2)
```

Most people don't expect variables to behave like this, however. So if you're writing code that others will be reading, I don't recommend using this feature of R. Explicitly update `b` when `a` changes or make `b` a function of `a`.

Comment: I feel compelled to add: "...and be sure to have fun debugging the resulting code!" ;)

Comment: I appreciate the added warning at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Warning: This isn't a good idea and task callbacks really should only be used if you know what you're doing.

You can do something like this but it's tedious and there are better ways to achieve your goal.  You can make a function that will be called after every top level evaluation that basically does the reassignment for you.

```
modified <- function(expr, value, ok, visible){
  if(exists("a")){
    assign("b", a*2, env = .GlobalEnv)
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

addTaskCallback(modified)
```

After running that you should be able to get this...

```
> a
Error: object 'a' not found
> b
Error: object 'b' not found
> a <- 2
> a
[1] 2
> b
[1] 4
> a <- 3
> a
[1] 3
> b
[1] 6
```

Note that if you want to emulate a spreadsheet it would probably just be better to define a function to take your input and do all the necessary calculations to get your desired output.  R isn't Excel and it would be best if you don't treat it like Excel.

Comment: I upvoted to counter the downvote. Is there any advantage to doing it this way rather than the way in my answer below (at least in the context of a user working interactively in R and defining functions in that environment)?

Comment: @Aristocrates You can be slightly lazier with the method in my post but it takes more work upfront and it's pretty easy to mess up callbacks.  I prefer your approach.  Actually I would typically do things the way Spacedman did in his post and just have a script to do all the calculations but either of those methods I would prefer to the method in my answer.  I just felt that since it technically is possible to do what they want I would provide that answer even if I don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

R doesn't work like that. Variables only change when assigned new values. This is a good thing, because it means things don't change magically. Suppose in 20 lines time you want to know the value of `b`? When did it change? What does it depend on?

R is not a spreadsheet.

Just to spell it out a bit more.

```
sales = 100
costs = 90
profit = sales - costs
```

now `profit` has the value 10.

```
sales = 120
```

Only `sales` has changed.

```
profit = sales - costs
```

That changes `profits` to 30.

If you have a complex calculation you would normally write a function:

```
computeProfit = function(sales, costs){return(sales - costs)}
```

and then do:

```
profit = computeProfit(sales, costs)
```

whenever you want to compute the profits from the sales and the costs.

Answer (score 0):

Although what you want to do is not *completely* possible in R, with a simple modification of `b` into a function and thanks to lexical scoping, you actually **can** have a "dependent variable" (sort of).

Define a:

```
a <- 1
```

Define b like this:

```
b <- function() {
    a*2
}
```

Then, instead of using `b` to get the value of b, use `b()`

```
b() ##gives 2
a <- 4
b() ##gives 8
```

Comment: Never say something isn't possible in R ;)